# Function arguments: upper bound vs parent class as argument?

Tags: scala, types, parameters, function-declaration

Consider we have:

```
abstract class FlyingObject;
case class Rocket(name: String) extends FlyingObject;
```

what is difference between those two function declarations:

```
def launch[T <: FlyingObject](fo: T)
```

and

```
def launch(fo: FlyingObject)
```

Great would be some examples when to use which type of declaration...

**[UPDATE]**

Another great example and explanation can be found [there](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Upper-Type-Bounds-td1999781.html). It's another example of when you should use upper bound instead of just derived class as parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be useful to have a T which is more specific than FlyingObject.  Perhaps imagine you have a method

```
def modifyName(fo: FlyingObject, newName: String): FlyingObject = fo.copy(name=newName)
```

Which returns a copy of the FlyingObject with a modified name.  That makes this code not typecheck:

```
val newRocket: Rocket = modifyName(oldRocket, "new name")
```

Since modifyName returns a FlyingObject not a Rocket.  instead:

```
def modifyName[T <: FlyingObject](fo: T, newName: String): T = fo.copy(name=newName)
```

Will return a Rocket when Rocket is what is passed in.

Comment: In other words, it matter specifically when the return type is type T.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge: perhaps when its used anywhere else in the type signature.  For you might want `def compare[T<:FlyingObject](one: T, two: T)` also

Answer (score 4):

In addition to  @stew answer, an upper bound could be useful when using typeclasses. For instance,
suppose you want a method that take two flying objects as well as a collider object defining how to manage collision with other objects. Of course, an asteroid-asteroid collision is not the same as a spaceship-asteroid collision (classical textbook example).

You could write such method as:

```
def collide[A <: FlyingObject, B <: FlyingObject]
  ( a: A, b: B )( implicit collider: Collider[A,B] ) = collider.apply(a,b)
```

Then the compiler will provide a correct `Collider` for you. If instead you wrote:

```
def collide( a: FlyingObject, b: FlyingObject ) = a.collide(b)
```

You will have to rely on Obect-Oriented feature to manage the collision which will be really difficult to write and to maintain (double dispatch issue).

Comment: Great addition to the answer of @stew.. +1